# How to check the text inside a textbox on a random slide in VBA (PowerPoint)?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

For a presentation I am making, I want to check if the text inside a textbox (the name of that textbox is *TextBox2* and is an ActiveX-control) is the same as the text in another textbox (the name of this textbox is *naam* but is not an ActiveX-control). This is the code I have now:

```
Dim osld As Slide
Set osld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide

Dim vragen As Byte
Dim juist As Byte
Dim fout As Byte

If osld.Shapes("TextBox2").TextFrame.TextRange = osld.Shapes("naam").TextFrame.TextRange Then
osld.Shapes("TextBox2") = ""
```

When I want to run this code, I get an error (Method or data member not found).

How can I make this code working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activepresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text

Instead of

```
If osld.Shapes("TextBox2").TextFrame.TextRange = etc
```

use

```
If osld.Shapes("TextBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Text = etc
```

and

```
osld.Shapes("TextBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Text = ""
```